# Jquery form, nnlimited fields and validation on each row

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a html form, which like this:

I have 2 fields, name and email, and 2 buttons, "add row" and "submit".

When i click the "add row" button, it will create a new row with 2 new fields (name and email). I store the name and email in array: ...

Thus, user can ad unlimited rows. I want to have a validation, if the user fill in either name or email on the same row, i want the user to fill in another field, so that every row would have "name" and "email" filled.

How to validate that, if 1 of the field is filled, then the another field on the same row must be filled, in jquery??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's assume that your rows are divs with a `class="row"`, and the two fields also has classes as `fname` and `femail`.

Then, the script will be the following:

```
function oneFieldIsEmpty() 
{
    $(".row").each(function(){
        if($(this).find(".fname").val().length || $(this).find(".femail").val().length) {
            if(!$(this).find(".fname").val().length || !$(this).find(".femail").val().length) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, really appreciate it, I will try asap. and let you know the resut. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery form validation [plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) since that allows you to create rules that can validate against other jQuery Selectors so you can use `.nameclass + :input` or `.emailclass ~ :input`

Comment: yeah, i am using jquery form validation, but seems like cant found what i wanted..

Comment: i am a javascript + jquery newbie and noob